# PhoneGap iOS Submit Error: ITMS-90807: Invalid entitlement - How can I build with SDK 13 or later?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I created my app with PhoneGap Build and am attempting to submit the iOS version to the App Store for review. The app works fine in TestFlight but once I submit for review, I get an email with this error:

```
ITMS-90807: Invalid entitlement - The com.apple.developer.user-fonts is valid only for apps build with SDK 13 or later
```

I've tried upgrading to the latest PhoneGap version:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />
```

I've also tried updating my OS to High Sierra and used XCode 7.3.1's Application Loader to upload the file.

I've also searched for a way to specify in config.xml that I want the app to be built with SDK 13 and I can't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it doesn't solve the issue with SDK 13. It is not available right now. But you can solve your issue in another way:

Its complaining about the **native** Font's feature, this API you can disable in your "App ID Configuration". And you **can** use custom fonts in WebView further as usual. Go to "`Developer Account` → `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` `Identifiers` → `select your configuration` → `disable Fonts feature`".

*Note*: Your provision profile will be then invalid which uses this configuration. You have to create a new profile, and then replace your new mobileprovision file and build the app for ios again.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I don't really know what you mean about custom fonts in WebView, but can I include custom fonts via CSS like I was doing? (Including the font file and pointing to it in the CSS)

Comment: @raspberryh, yes, exactly - you can use the custom fonts via CSS.